# issue to write datas to file text - "DriveApp.createFile" insert not wanted comma

Tags: google-apps-script

I have to convert a vba macro to a google's spreadsheet script.
In  VBA, I open file (text format) and write data line by line, and at the end i close the file. I didn't find the way with google script.
In a last try, I put all the datas in an array, and I use  "DriveApp.createFile" ... but ... from the second line, a comma is inserted in the first character of each line.

[datas in the Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU7Qi.jpg)

[datas after the export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ToF7.jpg)

So, Is someone have a solution for my problem ?

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("INSITU"));
var Data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C11:D500").getValues();
var Tab1 = []
var Inc = 0
for (i in Data) {
    var RowData = Data[i];
    var PN_carte = RowData[0];
    var Version_carte = RowData[1];
  
    if (PN_carte != "ENDOFLINE" && PN_carte !="") { // end of data and over ?
      //var Line[Inc] = PN_carte.substring(1, 18).toUpperCase()+"|"+PN_carte.toUpperCase() +"|"+Version_carte.toUpperCase();
      if ( typeof Version_carte !="number"){ //full number
       Version_carte = Version_carte.toUpperCase() 
      }
      Tab1[Inc] = PN_carte.substring(1, 18).toUpperCase()+"|"+PN_carte.toUpperCase() +"|"+ Version_carte +"\r\n";
      //var Line = PN_carte.substring(1, 18).toUpperCase()+"|"+PN_carte.toUpperCase() +"|"+Version_carte.toUpperCase();
      //Browser.msgBox(Line);
     //DriveApp.createFile('tmp'+Inc+'.txt',Line );
    } else {
     //Browser.msgBox("ENDOFLINE"); //debug
    }
     Inc ++;
}
DriveApp.createFile('tmp.txt',Tab1,MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT ); //not working fine add comma before first character line 2 and over
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in your script, `Tab1` is an array. So when `DriveApp.createFile` is run, I thought that `Tab1` might be used as `Tab1.toString()`. So `,` might be used. In order to avoid this, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
DriveApp.createFile('tmp.txt',Tab1,MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT );
```

#### To:

```
DriveApp.createFile('tmp.txt', Tab1.join(""), MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
```

#### Reference:

- [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)